# Determining the number of occurrence of an event

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you a roll a fair die 5 times. Resulting in independent outcomes (X1, X2, X3, X4, X4)
And Random Variable S = sum of the 5 rolls

Find P(S = 10)

I'm having difficulty understanding deriving the number of times S = 10

```
(6, 1, 1, 1, 1) : 5 sample points
(5, 2, 1, 1, 1) : 20 sample points
(4, 3, 1, 1, 1) : 20 sample points
(4, 2, 2, 1, 1) : 30 sample points
(3, 3, 2, 1, 1) : 30 sample points
(3, 2, 2, 2, 1) : 20 sample points
```

More specifically how do you derive 5 , 20, 20, 30, 30 , 20 without having to literally list them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For $[\color\red6,\color\green1,\color\green 1,\color\green 1,\color\green 1]$ there are $\dfrac{5!}{\color\red1!\color\green4!               }= 5$ different permutations
- For $[\color\red5,\color\green2,\color\orange1,\color\orange1,\color\orange1]$ there are $\dfrac{5!}{\color\red1!\color\green1!\color\orange3!}=20$ different permutations
- For $[\color\red4,\color\green3,\color\orange1,\color\orange1,\color\orange1]$ there are $\dfrac{5!}{\color\red1!\color\green1!\color\orange3!}=20$ different permutations
- For $[\color\red4,\color\green2,\color\green 2,\color\orange1,\color\orange1]$ there are $\dfrac{5!}{\color\red1!\color\green2!\color\orange2!}=30$ different permutations
- For $[\color\red3,\color\red  3,\color\green 2,\color\orange1,\color\orange1]$ there are $\dfrac{5!}{\color\red2!\color\green1!\color\orange2!}=30$ different permutations
- For $[\color\red3,\color\green2,\color\green 2,\color\green 2,\color\orange1]$ there are $\dfrac{5!}{\color\red1!\color\green3!\color\orange1!}=20$ different permutations